# Error to pass variable to mail in Laravel Mail 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, email

I trying to send contact mail in Laravel 5.5, I read the docs and tried use method described in there, but not works. This is my code.

**This is my form**

```
    <form class="send_message" action="{{url('send_mail_error_card_r')}}" method="post">
      <div class="text_box">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <textarea id="send_mail_error_card" name="send_mail_error_card" rows="5" cols="40" class="form-control send_mail_error_card"></textarea>
        <div class="send_button_box">
        <button type="submit" id="send_message" class="btn btn-default">Enviar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

**My route**

```
Route::post('/send_mail_error_card_r', 'HomeController@send_mail_error_card_r');
```

**My Controller**

```
public function send_mail_error_card_r(Request $request)
{   $email = 'viniciusdemourarosa@gmail.com';
    $data['text'] = $request->send_mail_error_card;
    Mail::send('mail.contact', $data, function($message) use ($email){
      $message->from('vinicius.rosa@bolder.com.br', 'Contabileads Developer');
      $message->to($email);
      $message->subject("Atenção!");
    });
}
```

**My mail view**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    {{$data['text']}}
  </body>
</html>
```

**My Class Contact of Mail**

```
public function __construct($data)
{
  $this->data = $data;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('mail.contact')->with(['data', $this->data]);
}
```

**My config about mail**

*In `config/mail.php`*

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),
```

*In `config/services.php`*

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => 'secret',
    'secret' => 'secret',
],
```

*In `.ENV` file*

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=secret
MAIL_PASSWORD=secret
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

My code returns

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: data (View: /var/www/html/planos/resources/views/mail/contact.blade.php)
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: public function build()
{  $data = $this->data;
    return $this->view('mail.contact')->with(['data', $data]);
}

Comment: is $data public ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data property must be `public`:

```
public $data;
public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}
```

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#view-data):

> Typically, you will want to pass some data to your view that you can utilize when rendering the email's HTML. There are two ways you may make data available to your view. First, any `public` property defined on your mailable class will automatically be made available to the view

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks a lot, Alexey.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function build()
{  
    $data = $this->data;
    return $this->view('mail.contact')->with(['data', $data]);
}
```

This will work perfect for you. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Change this in your mail build function

```
->with(['data', $this->data]);
```

To this

```
->with(['data' => $this->data]);
```